# Pull Specific 10 digit string from filename

Tags: powershell

Most of our files are named in a uniform syntax:

```
B0????????.????.??????.jpg
```

However occassionaly we see:

```
?????.B0????????.????.jpg
```

or

```
?????????.B0????????.jpg
```

I need a PowerShell script to pull the 'B0' and the next 8 digits. Traditionally we have just trimmed the string when the file names are uniform, but that is failing with these variations.

Does anyone have a bit of PS logic that can pull 'B0' and the next 8 digits from a string/filename?

Thanks!

Comment: `-replace '.*(B0\d{8}).*', '$1'`

Comment: @AnsgarWiechers I don't think he's looking to rename the file.

Comment: @TheIncorrigible1 that doesn't rename it - you just modify the string.

Comment: @ConnorLSW Right, but he's just looking to pull the data from a string, so `-match` would suffice

Comment: @TheIncorrigible1 well you'd need to do `-match` then access `$Matches` - this does the exact same thing in one statement.

Answer (score 0):

```
$file = "?????.B0????????.????.jpg"
$index = ($file).IndexOf("B0")
$yourCharacters = ($file).Substring($index, 10)
$file.Replace($yourCharacters, "")
```

Comment: This can be shortened to `$File = "?????.B0????????.????.jpg" -replace '.*(b0.{8}).*', '$1.jpg'`